# kotest: automatically derive Generator from data class

Tags: kotlin, property-based-testing, kotest

I wonder if it's possible to automatically derive a Generator from a data class like e.g.  `scalacheck-shapeless`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is coming in 5.0. Recently merged to master, see [here](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/blob/master/kotest-property/src/jvmMain/kotlin/io/kotest/property/arbitrary/jvmbind.kt).